# Hibernate not setting reference column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using hibernate 4.3.7.Final on OSX with Mysql 5.5.8.

I have a joinTable relationship setup however my foreign keys fail to add:

```
[ERROR] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table T_USER_AUTHORITY add constraint FK_fr51fcyulxn31ijiotp4fx7i5 foreign key (email) references T_USER
[ERROR] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Can't create table 'carcloud.#sql-149c1_195' (errno: 150)
```

if I run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` I get the following:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
141106  5:48:00 Error in foreign key constraint of table carcloud/#sql-149c1_123:
 foreign key (email) references T_USER:
Syntax error close to:
```

if i run:

```
alter table T_USER_AUTHORITY add constraint FK_fr51fcyulxn31ijiotp4fx7i5 foreign key (email) references T_USER (email);
```

The constraint is successfully added, note (email) at the end which is the referencing column.

It is set as my primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE `T_USER` (
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_modified_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `OPT_LOCK` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: R u using annotations or xml configuration for mapping ?

Comment: @OO7 I'm using the annotations: https://gist.github.com/imduffy15/3b270c062a9fe18d57d7

Comment: Is there more information alfet `Syntax error close to:`?

Comment: Can use provide full mapping of *T_USER* & *T_USER_AUTHORITY* tables ? If u can, then update github link u have provided.

Comment: Which class is the owner of the relationship ?  *T_USER* or *T_USER_AUTHORITY*.

Comment: Sorry @OO7 pasted the wrong example. I have updated the gist.

Comment: @Ian Duffy You r mapping `@JoinTable(name = "T_USER_AUTHORITY"` to `private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();` in `User` class & on the other side, in `Authority` class, u have mapped the class with `@Table(name = "T_AUTHORITY")`. Is that correct ? Where is the mapping for `T_USER_AUTHORITY` table ?

Comment: I think, there is a *mistake* in mapping **Authority** class with **T_AUTHORITY** table. It *should be mapped* with **T_USER_AUTHORITY** table. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference that i see is in Hibernate "references T_USER" and in sql "references T_USER (email)" so you should insert java code that call "alter table T_USER_AUTHORITY add constraint FK_fr51fcyulxn31ijiotp4fx7i5 etc .. "

Comment: Hi @Mailkov I have no control over the statements. Hibernate auto generates them based off my classes. I'm using the auto generate ddl features.

Comment: You can post your classes ?

Comment: Sure @Mailkov here they are: https://github.com/imduffy15/carcloud-api/blob/introduce-device-entity/src/main/java/ie/ianduffy/carcloud/domain/User.java

I would note, using it against a h2 database the constraints were created without issue.